# Adding additional pages to a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I gave a controller called reports in my Rails 3 application. The index section of the controller looks like this:

```
def index
    #@reports = Report.all

    @clinical_income_by_month = Clinical.income_by_month                      
    @clinical_income_by_employee = Clinical.income_by_employee
    @clinical_income_by_vet = Clinical.income_by_vet                          
    @consult_consult_times = Consult.consult_times
      @clinical_healthplan_high_spenders = Clinical.healthplan_high_spenders

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @reports }
    end
  end
```

The index.html.erb code looks like this:

```
<h6><b>Financial Reports</b></h6>
    <dl class="vertical">
      <dd><a href="/income_by_month">Income by Month</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="/income_by_employee">Income by Employee</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="/income_by_vet">Income by Vet</a></dd>
 </dl>
```

I have split the reports which were originally all in index.html.erb under jQuery tabs into their own pages.

What is the best way to make the links to the individual reports load? Currenly if I visit the links or manually enter http://0.0.0.0:3000/reports/income_by_month.html I get an unknown page error.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your first steps is to add methods in your controller for each of the different reports. These go in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
resource :reports do
  member do
    get 'income_by_month'
    get 'income_by_employee'
    get 'income_by_vet'
  end 
end
```

The result of this is to give you paths to your reports of:

```
income_by_month_reports    GET    /reports/income_by_month
income_by_employee_reports GET    /reports/income_by_employee
income_by_vet_reports      GET    /reports/income_by_vet
```

Then, in your erb the best way to refer to the reports using `_path` variables like so:

```
<h6><b>Financial Reports</b></h6>
<dl class="vertical">
  <dd><a href='<%= income_by_month_reports_path %>'>Income by Month</a></dd>
  <dd><a href='<%= income_by_employee_reports_path %>'>Income by Employee</a></dd>
  <dd><a href='<%= income_by_vet_reports_path %>'>Income by Vet</a></dd>
</dl>
```

A good place for you to start is this primer called ["Ruby on Rails Guides: Rails Routing from the Outside In"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I've read through the guide but when I add your suggested routes I seem to need an ID in the URL. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I had a typo in my code. It should've been `resource`, not `resources`. `resources` assumes you have many of them so it wants the ``:id` of the one you're looking for. Sorry. The code above has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do it like this, by wiring up some routes to new actions in your controller:

```
# in config/routes.rb
map '/income_by_month',    :to => 'reports#income_by_month'
map '/income_by_employee', :to => 'reports#income_by_employee'
map '/income_by_vet',      :to => 'reports#income_by_vet'

# in reports_controller
def income_by_month
  @clinical_income_by_month = Clinical.income_by_month
end
def income_by_employee
  @clinical_income_by_employee = Clinical.income_by_employee
end
def income_by_vet
  @clinical_income_by_vet = Clinical.income_by_vet
end
```

But it seems to me, the Rails way to do this would be more like this:

```
# index.html.erb
<h6><b>Financial Reports</b></h6>
<dl class="vertical">
  <dd><a href="/reports?by=month">Income by Month</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="/reports?by=employee">Income by Employee</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="/reports?by=vet">Income by Vet</a></dd>
</dl>

# in reports_controller
def index
  @clinical_income = case params[:by]
  when 'month'    then Clinical.income_by_month                      
  when 'employee' then Clinical.income_by_employee
  else Clinical.income_by_vet
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :reports do
  collection do
    get "income_by_month"
    get "income_by_employee"
    get "income_by_vet"
  end
end
```

and map these functions in your reports controller